# Where are Github Organization invites?

Tags: github

I have been invited to a GitHub Organization but I can not find the invititation link anywhere in the website UI.

Does someone know where it is, so that I can accept it?

Comment: This question is off-topic. Ask the GitHub support instead. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Organization invites do not show up in my *GitHub notifications* section but in the *mail box* section instead.

So check your **GitHub mail box** instead.

Comment: This answer is more a guess or a comment than anything else. Definitely not an answer as defined by [answer]. Downvoted.